# Error on Value of Dictionary and List Declaration due to negative sign value C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, list, dictionary

What does this error mean on my code i see while debugging some output are negative which triggers this error while also in the other hand i saw a Dictionary with two parameters int and decimal but then to be stored to a list of int declare could this be also triggering the crash? what are the possible remedy for this crash error?

[Picture of the Error Message Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkFCn.jpg)

function is declared on a class called PriceTierModel

```
private Dictionary<int, decimal> _unitPrices = new Dictionary<int, decimal>(); // key == TurnTime
public void AddPrice(int turnTimeValue, decimal price)
        {
            _unitPrices[turnTimeValue] = price;
        }

    public List<int> TurnTimes
    {
        get
        {
            List<int> turnTimes = _unitPrices.Keys.ToList();
            turnTimes.Sort();
            return turnTimes;
        }
    }
```

which is used here in this other class

```
public override string Error
        {
            get
            {
                PriceTierModel priceTier = GetPriceTier();
                try
                {
                    if (priceTier != null && _desiredTurnTime < Math.Abs(priceTier.TurnTimes[0]))
                    {
                        return String.Format(CadFramework.Rm.GetString("TurnTimeTooSoon"), priceTier.TurnTimes[0]);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ei) { return String.Format(CadFramework.Rm.GetString("TurnTimeTooSoon"), Math.Abs(priceTier.TurnTimes[0])); }

                return "";
            }
        }
```

Added Code for Showing implementation use of the function.

```
foreach (XElement tier in priceTiers)
                {
                    // possible that the tier element is invalid
                    //<price_tier>
                    //  <turn_time></turn_time>
                    //  <unit_price>N/A</unit_price>
                    //  <turn_time_days>None days</turn_time_days>
                    //</price_tier>
                    int turnTime;
                    // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
                    if (int.TryParse(tier.Element("turn_time").Value, out turnTime))
                    {
                        decimal unitPrice = decimal.Parse(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tier.Element("unit_price").Value) ? tier.Element("unit_price").Value : "0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        priceTier.AddPrice(turnTime, unitPrice); <-- Here
                    }
                }
```

Comment: That error happens when you access an array and, let's say, the array has 3 items (so index 0, 1, and 2) in it but you are asking it for the fourth item (so index 3). The error will be that the index (3) is out of range because the range in this case is 0 to 2. Most likely your error is at this line: `_unitPrices[turnTimeValue]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means, that the line:

```
try
{
/* --> */ if (priceTier != null && _desiredTurnTime < Math.Abs(priceTier.TurnTimes[0]))
{
return String.Format(CadFramework.Rm.GetString("TurnTimeTooSoon"), priceTier.TurnTimes[0]);
}
```

or the line:

```
public void AddPrice(int turnTimeValue, decimal price)
{
/* --> */ _unitPrices[turnTimeValue] = price;
}
```

is entering or accessing (thanks to commentator) an item that is not existing in one of the both list.

From [MSDN (IndexOutOfRangeException)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The exception that is thrown when an attempt is made to access an
>   element of an array or collection with an index that is outside its
>   bounds.

Comment: Not only *entering* but both accessing and entering will cause the error.

Comment: Yes the Crash marks on that Spot i thought it was because it inserts negative numeric value which may cause the crash that is why i use Math.Abs but still Crash. is it possible because of passing a Dictionary which have two parameters to a list with only one parameter int?

Comment: You can not calculate somehow (Math.Abs or what so ever) the index. When you try to get/set an item of a list, you should expect that exactly this item is the item you want. The indexer of an list is beginning from 0 and by using a dictionary you are defining your own way to index. This can be each type. But that is more complicated, because you have to take care about the comparison of reference types...

Comment: @DMigzResearch arrays are like slots. If your array only has 2 slots and you ask for Math.Abs(-3), where will it get the third slot from? There is no 3rd slot.

Comment: private Dictionary<int, decimal> _unitPrices = new Dictionary<int, decimal>(); // key == TurnTime <-- sorry this is suppose to be add to this is how it declare the unitprice which has two slot and is inserted to list<int>

Comment: I think, this is what you want. By adding an item _unitPrices.Add(20,0.5), you can access it by _unitPrices[20], while using a list, you had to use _unitPrices[0], because of index begin at 0. Sorry, your last sentence could I not understand.

Comment: @CodingYoshi sir isn't Math.Abs use for rounding of Number to it's absolute value. and also often use for negative numeric result to convert them to positve by round it to it's nearest positive value.?? correct me if i'm wrong sir

Comment: That's not quite right. It just makes it positive but it does NOT round it. This you you can reach with Math.Floor or Math.Ceiling or by just cast decimal to int by using Convert.ToInt32(yourDecimal). Last approach does round to the nearest full integer number;

Comment: @DMigzResearch No it's not for rounding. It's for getting the absolute value so if you pass it -3, it will produce +3. But if you have an array with 2 slots, and you ask it for the 3rd slot, where is the 3rd slot? So what if 3 is positive, there is no 3rd slot. Read my comment above and my comment to your question, think about it for a few minutes and try to make sense of it.

Comment: @Bagerfahrer Sir i added / edit a code above the implementation of a function probably the error crash resulted due to the error that if i expanded my CAD graph to it's exceed height and width it automatically takes out the turntimes value the days 3,4,5 is set to empty so when i process it the value is empty? is it possible by that sir?

Comment: @DMigzResearch did you see my 5th comment to your question?

Comment: @CodingYoshi yes sir i understand about the Math.Abs

Comment: @DMigzResearch no there is no 5th comment to your question. There is just 1 comment. And that is what the error is also saying that it cannot find something because it does not exist in the array.

Comment: What he wants to tell you is: you should think about what is happening to your list, what's inside, and what you want access and is accessible by thinking about it. We can not help you, because we can not know what's inserting and accessing to your list, so that we can diagnose your exception.

Comment: i'm still tracing it.. i'm only a debugger didn't create this system yes it's hard on my part too.. sorry sir but you did made help by giving me a idea of what is going on.. i'll need to trace more probably by your ideas shared it help me where to look and i see that clearly it's the list that troubles which i need to focus on it.

Comment: this system is like exploring Forest to me.. given the task i have to explore while debug problems of this unknown system to me without debrief..

Comment: True, but it just can make you stronger. Just continue, research or ask here for information. You get help, but you have to do something too.